# Wanted: elegant solution for S3 generic body if object can't be found

Tags: r, oop, generics, methods

This is just a MWE of more complex code I'm writing.

Suppose I want to create a new method `newMethod` that (among other things) needs to extract a variable `x` from a dataframe `data`, but also needs to extract some additional properties from `data` (e.g., its column names).

I've first defined the S3 generic as follows

```
newMethod <- function(x, data) UseMethod("newMethod")
```

In order to extract `x` from `data` I've written `newMethod.default`:

```
newMethod.default <- function(x, data) {
  x <- eval(substitute(x), envir = data)
  return(list(x = x, names = names(data)))
}
```

Depending on `class(x)` I then plan to do further dispatching (probably inside `newMethod.default`, before returning the list), but that doesn't really matter here (I just mention it here to explain why I'm creating a generic function in the first place).

However, when I test this generic by running

```
newMethod(mpg, mtcars)
```

I get the (perhaps not surprising) error message: `Error in newMethod(mpg, mtcars) : object 'mpg' not found`. So now I was wondering what would be the best workaround. My intuition would be to move part of the code from `newMethod.default` to `newMethod` as I do here

```
newMethod <- function(x, data) {
  x <- eval(substitute(x), envir = data)
  UseMethod("newMethod", x)
}
```

but I'm not quite sure whether this is common or good practice, partly because [it's suggested not to use the second argument of `UseMethod`](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html#s3). In addition, I need to leave the first line of `newMethod.default` untouched, otherwise I again end up with an error message.

I'ld be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction, as I have the feeling I'm not quite on the right track on this one. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you get an error with `newMethod(mpg, mtcars)`? it should work fine.

Comment: I guess because `mpg` isn't in the calling environment (global workspace). You managed to run the code without any errors?

Comment: yes without any problem... But why are you using `names` and bother yourself with eval/subsitute? why not just use the column names. Somethine like .`newMethod.default <- function(x, data) {
  list(x = data[,x], names = names(data))}` and then call it `newMethod("mpg", mtcars)`.

Comment: I still haven't managed to run the first version of the generic without returning any errors (not even on [compileonline.com](http://compileonline.com)). `names` is just a simplified illustration I'm using in order to show that I need additional operations on `data` (in order to make `newMethod` seem less trivial). It might indeed seem quite trivial here. Your suggestion to limit `x` to the use of characters might indeed offer the most simple solution. For some reason I can't remember I had abandoned this option in my original code. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens, has nothing to do with the method, but simply with how R reads your code. It looks at the first argument and decides to do some dispatching based on that. But the problem is that this object `mpg` doesn't exist, so R has no way to decide what method should be called. R needs to be able to determine the class of that object. "Doesn't exist" is not a class, so it's impossible to dispatch on an object that doesn't exist in the environment where the function is called from.

Take a look at the `with()` function and the defaut method `with.default()`. That does basically what you're doing here but in a bit more a general way. It's default method is actually almost exactly the same as your example:

```
> with.default
function (data, expr, ...) 
eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
<bytecode: 0x0825d7d8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

The important part is that `with()` takes the data argument as a first argument, and the expression (in your case simply `mpg`) as a second. This way it doesn't matter `mpg` doesn't exist in the calling frame, as R only looks at the first argument when trying to dispatch.

So this works:

```
newMethod <- function( data, x) UseMethod("newMethod")

newMethod.default <- function(data, x) {
  x <- eval(substitute(x), envir = data)
  return(list(x = x, names = names(data)))
}
```

On a sidenote: Think again about the dispatching from within `newMethod.default`. Not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but I feel this is something where you would use `NextMethod` for. But that's tricky business to get working, and in that case it might be far more convenient to move over to S4, for the simple reason that you can use S4 methods for combinations of classes and even for missing arguments. But as long as you stay in S3, there's no way to catch a non-existing object, apart from using `exists()` in the generic function, for example:

```
newMethod <- function( data, x) {
  if(exists(deparse(substitute(x))))
  UseMethod("newMethod")}
```

But this is code I wouldn't use myself.

Comment: Many thanks! I'ld really like to use dispatching based on `x`, so your suggestion (although helpful in other settings) wouldn't be a solution here I guess. Regarding dispatching: the inspiration for doing this from within `newMethod.default` was inspired by `summary.default`. I think the most elegant solution is given by @agstudy: limit `x` to character strings. Still, I was wondering whether there's examples of S3 generics including code other than `UseMethod(...)`.

Comment: @johansteen You can only dispatch on existing objects, so if you limit x to character strings, you'll be dispatching to `newMethod.character` every time.  My last piece of code is an example where you find more code in the generic, but it's generally advised against